# RSS feed not validating

Tags: rss

my RSS feed is not validating properly and i cannot see why.. i get the following errors:

```
This feed does not validate.
line 2, column 0: Undefined root element: xml [help]
<xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'>
line 16, column 2: XML parsing error: <unknown>:16:2: mismatched tag [help]
</item>
  ^
```

I see the errors but i dont get why the are there since i dont see the issue within the code. But i am a newbie with this so..

```
<xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'>
<rss version='2.0'> 
<channel>
    <title>Uppladdade bilder</title>
    <description>Uppladdade bilder</description>
    <br>
    <link>http://douglaspettersson.se/moment5/rss.php</link>
    <hr>
    <br>
<item>
<description>Uppladdad av: doggepe</description>
<br><img src="uploads/thumb_laferrari.jpg"/>
<br><description> Bildbeskrivning: Ferrari LaFerrari</description>
<br><link> http://douglaspettersson.se/moment55/uploads/thumb_laferrari.jpg</link><br><pubdate> Uppladdad: 2016-02-14 22:21:19</pubdate>
</item>

<hr><br><item>
<description>Uppladdad av: doggepe</description>
<br><img src="uploads/thumb_porsche991.jpg"/>
<br><description> Bildbeskrivning: 2014 Porsche 911 Carrera</description>
<br><link> http://douglaspettersson.se/moment55/uploads/thumb_porsche991.jpg</link><br><pubdate> Uppladdad: 2016-02-14 22:23:55</pubdate>
</item>

<hr><br><item>
<description>Uppladdad av: mattias</description>
<br><img src="uploads/thumb_DSC_0050.JPG"/>
<br><description> Bildbeskrivning: Höga kusten</description>
<br><link> http://douglaspettersson.se/moment55/uploads/thumb_DSC_0050.JPG</link><br><pubdate> Uppladdad: 2016-02-17 07:24:00</pubdate>
</item>

<hr><br><item>
<description>Uppladdad av: doggepe</description>
<br><img src="uploads/thumb_etihad.jpg"/>
<br><description> Bildbeskrivning: Etihad A330-300</description>
<br><link> http://douglaspettersson.se/moment55/uploads/thumb_etihad.jpg</link><br><pubdate> Uppladdad: 2016-03-02 19:30:54</pubdate>
</item>

<hr><br><item>
<description>Uppladdad av: doggepe</description>
<br><img src="uploads/thumb_s105.jpg"/>
<br><description> Bildbeskrivning: Saab 105</description>
<br><link> http://douglaspettersson.se/moment55/uploads/thumb_s105.jpg</link><br><pubdate> Uppladdad: 2016-03-02 19:31:26</pubdate>
</item>

<hr><br><item>
<description>Uppladdad av: doggepe</description>
<br><img src="uploads/thumb_italia.jpg"/>
<br><description> Bildbeskrivning: Disko</description>
<br><link> http://douglaspettersson.se/moment55/uploads/thumb_italia.jpg</link><br><pubdate> Uppladdad: 2016-03-08 13:20:43</pubdate>
</item>

<hr><br><item>
<description>Uppladdad av: doggepe</description>
<br><img src="uploads/thumb_porscheLogin.jpg"/>
<br><description> Bildbeskrivning: pratzny</description>
<br><link> http://douglaspettersson.se/moment55/uploads/thumb_porscheLogin.jpg</link><br><pubdate> Uppladdad: 2016-03-08 13:21:08</pubdate>
</item>

<hr><br><a href="http://douglaspettersson.se/moment55/index.php">Tillbaka till webbplatsen</a>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the RSS specs, or at least an example RSS file, and compared your first line (the one that throws the error) to a correct version? This should be trivial to fix.

Comment: I have, does not seem to be a difference which is weird.

Comment: Have you ever resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

What qre the `br` tags? They don`t belong in RSS feeds!